# why converges absolutely needed for that prove *?*

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

> **Theorem**: If  $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges absolutely, then any rearrangement of this series converges to the same limit.

I will try to prove without using converges absolutely condition. 
**proof**: Assume $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges absolutely to A. Let $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_k$ be a rearrangement of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ and $$t_m=\sum_{k=1}^{m} b_k=b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_m$$
for the partial sums of the rearranged series. Thus we want to show that $(t_m)\rightarrow A$. Let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $N_1$ such that $|s_n-A|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ $(\text{By hypothesis})$ for all $n\geq N_1$. Again using cauchy criterion for series there exists an $N_2$ $\in \mathbb{N}$ such that whenever $n>m\geq N_2$ $$\left|\sum_{m+1}^{n} a_k\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ Now take $N=\max\{ N_1,N_2\}$. we know that the finite set of terms $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots,a_N \}$ must all appear in the rearranged series, and we want to move far enough out in the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ so that we have included all of these terms. Thus choose M=max{$f(k):1\leq k\leq N$ }. It should now be evident that if $m\geq M$, then $(t_m-s_N)$ consists of a finite set of terms. And so
\begin{align*}
|t_m-A|=|t_m-s_N+s_N-A|\leq |t_m-s_N|+|s_N-A|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon
\end{align*}
whenever $m\geq M$. 
Is my proof is correct $?$ If not then where is the problem and why converges absolutely needed at all. Any explanation or solution will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is not correct and it could not be since you did not use the assumption that the series converges absolutely. So, what you proved contradicts the [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).

The error in your proof lies in assuming that if you take $N$ large enough so that$$m\geqslant n\geqslant N\implies\left\lvert\sum_{k=n}^nb_k\right\rvert<\frac\varepsilon2,$$then, if you take *some* $a_k$'s all of which are such that $k\geqslant N$, then the absolute values of their sum will still be smaller than $\frac\varepsilon2$.

Comment: Carlos Santos Sir I actually want to see if it is possible to prove this theorem without using converges absolutely condition

Comment: No, you cannot, because, as I wrote in my answer, if the statement would hold without the assumption of absolute convergence, then the Riemann rearrangement thorem would be false.

Comment: Now I can related why it's necessary Thanks @Jose Carlos Santos Sir

Answer (score 2):

The "finite set of terms" making up $(t_m-s_N)$ need not be consecutive, i..e, their sum need not be of the form $\sum_{k_1}^{k_2}a_k$ and thus need not be bounded by $\frac \epsilon2$.

Comment: Yes here is the problem. I use cauchy criterion but without concerned about their index. Thanks @Hagen Von Eitzen Sir

Answer (score 0):

You can't prove it without assuming absolute convergence, because the statement is false without that assumption. For example, the alternating harmonic series
$$1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15-\frac16+\frac17-\frac18+\frac19-\frac1{10}+\cdots$$
converges conditionally, but the rearrangement
$$1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15-\frac16-\frac18+\frac17-\frac1{10}-\frac1{12}-\frac1{14}-\frac1{16}+\frac19-\frac1{18}-\frac1{20}-\frac1{22}-\frac1{24}-\frac1{26}-\frac1{28}-\frac1{30}-\frac1{32}+\frac1{11}-\cdots$$
does not converge, as it fails the Cauchy criterion: each block of consecutive negative terms has a sum $\le-\frac14$.

Comment: Can you put these block highlighted as it seem confused to find $\leq \frac{-1}{4}$ @bof Sir.

Comment: @emonhossain I don't understand your comment. What are you confused about? What is it you want highlighted?